# How do i convert this jQuery code into jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have some jQuery codes, which is repeated again and again, i would like to reduce the code i am writing that is by converting it into functions. here is the codes i am using.

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user"]').click(function() {
    var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg === 'empty') {
                alert('Required Values Missing');
            } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                alert('Email already exist');
            } else {
                window.location = "index.php?users&option=edit&user_id="+msg+'&msg=success';
            }
        }
    });
});

$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').click(function() {
    var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg === 'empty') {
                alert('Required Values Missing');
            } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                alert('Email already exist');
            } else {
                window.location = 'index.php?users';
            }
        }
    });
});

$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-new"]').click(function() {
    var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg === 'empty') {
                alert('Required Values Missing');
            } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                alert('Email already exist');
            } else {
                window.location = 'index.php?users&option=create';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to know few things,

> **a)** With reference to above code, how do i convert it to
>   function, as the code have very few changes like, selector name and
>   url of window.location.
>
> **b)** what do i call the code below, is it the function? function on
>   the go? or dynamic function?

```
$('selector').event(function(){
     //jQuery Code in wake of event being triggered.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write a small plugin for it:

```
(function ($) {

jQuery.fn.myClick = function (destination) {
    this.click(function () { 
        var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'process.php',
            data: formData,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg === 'empty') {
                    alert('Required Values Missing');
                } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                    alert('Email already exist');
                } else {
                    window.location = destination(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

}(jQuery));
```

Then to call it you would simply do:

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').myClick(function() {
    return 'index.php?users&option=create';
});
```

and

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user"]').myClick(function (msg) {
    return "index.php?users&option=edit&user_id="+msg+'&msg=success';
});
```

You should be able to see where we're going here; we're adding parameters to the small method we've created, where you can specify what changes between each call.

Because in this instance, the `window.location` depends on the AJAX response (and we don't know the response when we invoke the function!), we can't simply provide a string (or something similar) as the parameter. Instead, we pass a function which we invoke once the AJAX response is received, provided the `msg` as a variable; and rely on the function to provide a string which we set to the `window.location`.

---

As for your second question, you pass an **event handler** to the jQuery event methods; an event handler will be a *function reference* (usually a reference to an *anonymous function*)

Comment: i was about to post my answer but i saw this cool answer..thanks for sharing..+1

Comment: yeah, i was looking for this kind of answer, i am willing to make a plugin out of the code.

Answer (score 4):

**a)**
I would start by taking the changing fields as params:

```
function doPost(redirectUrl) {
    var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg === 'empty') {
                alert('Required Values Missing');
            } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                alert('Email already exist');
            } else {
                window.location = redirectUrl.indexOf("{0}") >= 0 ? redirectUrl.replace("{0}", msg) : redirectUrl;
            }
        }
    });
}

$('form#save-user button[name="save-user"]').click(function() {
    doPost("index.php?users&option=edit&user_id={0}&msg=success");
});

$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').click(function() {
    doPost("index.php?users");    
});
```

**b)**
I would call it an anonymous eventhandler (function).

Comment: this doesn't seems like jQuery function instead to me it looks like native javascript function, i know this will work, but is it considered a good practice to go this way?

Comment: You may as well bind the button : doBind(buttonName) which bind the button onclick to doPost.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you wanted a plugin out of this. I would have changed my answer but then @Matt's already has posted it :).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you :

JQuery :

```
function saveuser(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg === 'empty') {
                alert('Required Values Missing');
            } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                alert('Email already exist');
            } else {
                window.location = "index.php?users&option=...';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML :

```
<element onClick="saveuser('the-form-data')"></element>
```

Comment: i do not want to add onClick() event in my html element field, instead i would like to go with jQuery plugin kind of thing :)

Comment: Was reading Matt's solution, seems like a much better solution, with or without the onClick() issu.